# What's the difference between 浮かぶ and 浮く?

Tags: word-choice

I often see 浮く in contexts relating to floatability, like:

```
氷は水に浮きます
```

However, sometimes I see 浮く used where I'd use 浮かぶ.
When should one be used over the other?
Are there any cases where both are acceptable?

Comment: You should add `浮かべる` too.

Comment: Can it's meaning not be deduced from 浮かぶ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

浮く to float, float to the surface.
「魚が浮いた」
「泡が浮く」
「木が水に浮く」
「空に浮く」

浮かぶ to be floating at a surface, float with no movement (think of the かぶ like ~ている）。
「氷が浮かぶ」
「白雲が浮かぶ」

Comment: To whoever down voted me, this is how my Japanese-Japanese dictionary explains it (大辞林).

Comment: Does your dictionary say 魚が浮た, not 魚が浮いた? (ところでダウンボートしたの私じゃないです)

Comment: @Jon: It seems to me like 浮く is simply an antonym of 沈む, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @DanielSafari In meaning and being intransitive, sure. "simply~" is not how I would make statements about high-context languages, however.

Comment: @Jon: Could you elaborate? I'm not quite sure I follow, since in this case it seems "simply" applies? Or do you mean generally about Japanese?